# From object to array with revert and regroup

Tags: javascript, array

Basically, I need to regroup *keys* by *values* from an object to an array

An example worth a thousand words in my case, as I don't know how to clearly explain my problem.

Here is my **input object**:

```
{
    "Data 1": 0,
    "Data 2": 1,
    "Data 3": 3,
    "Data 4": 0
}
```

What I should output:

```
[
    ["Data 1", "Data 4"], // data 1 and 4 are grouped as they both "worth" 0
    ["Data 2"], // data 2 is alone to "worth" 1
    ["Data 3"] // data 3 is alone to "worth" 3
]
```

**First solution:**

```
var output = [];
for (var data in input) { // my input object
    var value = input[data];
    if (output[value] == undefined) {
        output[value] = [];
    }
    output[value].push(data);
}
console.log(output);
```

It works well for most of the cases, except the one presented at the beginning: if I skip a value - say 0, 1, 3 - then my output will be

```
[
    0: ["Data 1", "Data 4"],
    1: ["Data 3"],
    3: ["Data 4"]
]
```

What I understood so far is that *since the key `2` is missing, JavaScript somehow understand the output as an associative array*.

**Final solution:**

From the code below, I used a "trick", making an equivalent of `array_values()` from PHP:

```
function array_values(arr) {
    var tmp = [];
    for (key in arr) {
        tmp[tmp.length] = arr[key];
    }
    return tmp;
}

var output = [];
for (var data in input) { // my input object
    var value = input[data];
    if (output[value] == undefined) {
        output[value] = [];
    }
    output[value].push(data);
}
console.log(array_values(output));
```

This finally works perfectly fine.

Nevertheless, I feel like I could optimize and simplify my code. I fear that a big object could be long to process since I could have to parse it 2 times. Does anyone have a guess?

Comment: It would be easier to think that JavaScript does not have arrays and only have objects that allow numeric properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the values are no longer needed in the output array and that you only want to construct the final array that you receive after the call to your `array_values` function.

```
// I extend the data with another duplicated value for a better test.
var input = { "Data 1": 0, "Data 2": 1, "Data 3": 3, "Data 4": 0, "Data 5": 3 };

// No change, our output array.
var output = [];

// We will use an additional array to create a mapping between actual values
// and the output array's indices they are stored at.
var mapping = [];

for (var data in input) {
    // Check if the value of this input data is already present in the
    // mapping's array, if it is, append the actual data to the already
    // existing array.
    //
    // NOTE: Using `mapping[input[data]] == undefined` is not a secure method
    // to check if an array index exists, since the value might be undefined
    // and that is not what we want. It is like `isset` and `array_key_exists`
    // in PHP, if you are familiar with that language.
    if (input[data] in mapping) {
        // We access the output array via the mappings array and the original
        // input arrays value and push the data.
        output[mapping[input[data]]].push(data);
        // output[0].push("Data 4");
        // output[2].push("Data 5");
    }
    // No entry exists in the mapping's array.
    else {
        // Push will simply append the data, we also inline the creation of the
        // desired array for additional data for this index.
        output.push([ data ]);
        // output[0] = [ "Data 1" ];
        // output[1] = [ "Data 2" ];
        // output[2] = [ "Data 3" ];

        // Now we need to create the actual mapping in case other data has the
        // same value. We simply create a new index and store the output
        // array's current index there (note the `-1` since `length` starts at
        // one in contrast to the indices which start at zero).
        mapping[input[data]] = output.length - 1;
        // mapping[0] = 0;
        // mapping[1] = 1;
        // mapping[3] = 2;
    }
}

console.dir(output);
```

Comment: You're assuming is good. I seems to work great! Thank you